# Как добавить дополнительные поля в форму регистрации Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

На кастомной странице регистрации есть форма регистрации, у которой пока есть поля: `login` и `email`. Добавил еще несколько полей в форму, например `номер телефона`, `адрес` и т.д. Создал в таблице `users` поля под новые поля в форме, но данные из полей формы не записываются в БД.
Как сделать чтоб кастомные поля записывались в БД ?

Comment: просто создать колонку в Бд мало конечно.. найди в коде где ворпресс отправляет данные в БД и добавь аналогично свои значения.. нужно будет несколько файлов редактировать.

Comment: Это уже сделал, все должно писать в БД, только как бы WP новых полей в БД не видит, мб мх нужно где-то инициализировать?

Comment: Правило1 - Никогда не лезть в базу руками. НИКОГДА! Правило2- использовать гуглояндексы. Там столько рецептов. А писать тут мануалы вряд ли кто-то будет. Правило 3 - стоит использовать плагины.

Comment: тут сложный вопрос... проверь полный путь работы с полем логина и пароля в вп..а лучше чтоб  те 2 поля в админке отдельно пользователь вводил - тут уже простой запрос в БД пойдет с известным id текущего пользователя..

Comment: но проще всего найти готовый плагин и если есть возможность настроить в админке.. ну или самому в коде немножко подправить.. тут уже от ваших знаний зависит (P.S никогда не любил ВП=))

Comment: @Volodymyr луше не пытаться помогать, когда не знаешь и не любишь предмета

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не стоит вмешиваться в базу данных WordPress, пока вы не уверены на 100% в том, что вы делаете. Это может привести к непредсказуемым последствиям.

Кастомные данные пользователя нужно хранить метаданных пользователя, создавать, обновлять и удалять их посредством функций `add_user_meta`, `update_user_meta`, `delete_user_meta`.

Для большинства потребностей в расширении WP есть хуки. В частности, для данного случая тоже все предусмотрено. Код ниже нужно добавить в functions.php вашей темы.

```
//1. Добавляем новый элемент в форму
add_action( 'register_form', 'myplugin_register_form' );
function myplugin_register_form() {

    $first_name = ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) ? trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) : '';

    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="first_name"><?php _e( 'First Name', 'mydomain' ) ?><br />
            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr( wp_unslash( $first_name ) ); ?>" size="25" /></label>
    </p>
    <?php
}

//2. Добавляем проверку, если этот элемент обязателен
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'myplugin_registration_errors', 10, 3 );
function myplugin_registration_errors( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {

    if ( empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) || ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) && trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) == '' ) {
        $errors->add( 'first_name_error', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must include a first name.', 'mydomain' ) );
    }

    return $errors;
}

//3. Сохраняем новое поле в метаданных пользователя
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_user_register' );
function myplugin_user_register( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) );
    }
}
```

Результат работы кода выглядит так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посмотреть работающую форму можно [здесь](http://test.kagg.eu/wp-login.php?action=register).

Comment: Но в таком случае данные поля first name не приходят на почту (письмо о регистрации нового пользователя)

Comment: @ЛюбовьДобровская а почему они должны туда приходить? В вопросе об этом ни слова.